# AngularJS - Reset form using $setPristine() when all controls are emptied

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a reusable directive that will simply reset my form and it's child controls to pristine using the [$setPristine()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/733a97adf87bf8f7ec6be22b37c4676cf7b5fc2b) method IF all the form's input controls are emptied after the user has previously interacted with them and marked them dirty.

So basically the directive would monitor all the form `<input>` elements and if it determines all elements are empty call [$setPristine()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/733a97adf87bf8f7ec6be22b37c4676cf7b5fc2b) to reset everything back to square one.

This seems kind of trivial and something I could bust out with jQuery in 5 mins but I'm just getting my feet wet with Angular and I've been stumbling around this for a couple of hours struggling with the best approach so any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Edit, easier answer:  Use the `require` or `ng-require` attribute on the form elements, keeping the form `$pristine` if there is an error.

If require is not wanted:

Note - you need angular version 1.1.x  for $setPristine().

Assuming all of the `ng-model`'s in the form are properties of the same object, you could `$watch` the object, loop through the properties to see if they are `undefined` or `''` empty strings, and `$setPristine()` if they are.

Form HTML - all of the models are properties of `input` object:

```
<form name="form">
  <input type="text" name="one" ng-model="input.one">
  <input type="text" name="two" ng-model="input.two"><br/>
  <input type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$pristine">
</form>
```

In the controller or directive, $watch the model for changes, then loop through the object, seeing if all properties are `undefined` or `''`.  (If used in the link function, you would typically use `scope` in place of `$scope`.

```
var setPristine = function(input){
    if (input === undefined || input === ''){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

$scope.$watch('input', function(i){
    var flag = 0;
    //loop through the model properties
    for (var obj in i){
        flag +=setPristine(i[obj]);
    }
    // if nothing in the model object, setPristine()
    if(flag===0){
        $scope.form.$setPristine();
    }
}, true)// true allows $watch of object properties, with some overhead
```

Comment: Thanks for this! The question I have is - using this example in a reusable directive wouldn't really work because it depends on a model called 'input' - I have numerous models 'user', 'product' etc. so I was hoping to just examine the generic form `<input>` elements of any form rather than examine the underlying model.  Is it possible to use `$watch` or some equivalent on the `<input>` elements?

Comment: Sure, I'm trying it now.  $watching an attribute object is proving a bit tricky ;).

Answer (score 0):

Use the dirty/pristine states of the form to know if user has touched them, and a ng-pattern to know if the field is empty or not with a regexp like `/.+/`. Then you can just check myForm.$dirty and myForm.$error.pattern and voila!